# MySql Joins not working

Tags: mysql

i have three tables named locations, locations1, bus. I want to join locations with bus on locations.id = bus.id and i want to join locations1 with locations on locations1.id = locations.id is below is the correct syntax of doing so?

```
SELECT bus.id, bus.from_here, 
       bus.to_here, bus.ac, bus.fair,
       bus.dates, locations, locations1 
FROM bus 
INNER JOIN locations ON locations.id = bus.id 
INNER JOIN locations1 ON locations1.id = locations.id  
WHERE dates = '".$_SESSION['depart']."'
```

Comment: Have you executed the query ?

Comment: It might be, but if the date is date/time vs just date and you dont have match on an exact date/time might be an issue.  Also, the IDs, a bus.id to a location.id?  as long as the ID represents the same thing you are ok, but if the bus.id represents the bus and locations.id represents a location, you wont get what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

`Select` reserve just for column names or `*` to indicate all.

```
locations, locations1
```

This should not work (If you meant the tables).

**You should use:**

```
locations.*, location1.*
```

Although i would suggest against it and to use specific column names you need inside those tables.

**For example:**

```
locations.Field1, location.Field2, location1.OtherField1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to be selecting specific fields from the tables locations and locations1.

Like... just an example... select more fields as needed. Or you can use `*` to SELECT all fields from a table. Do remember this will be slower than if you specify fields as shown below.

```
SELECT bus.id, bus.from_here, 
       bus.to_here, bus.ac, bus.fair,
       bus.dates, locations.id, locations1.id
FROM bus 
INNER JOIN locations ON locations.id = bus.id 
INNER JOIN locations1 ON locations1.id = locations.id  
WHERE bus.dates = '".$_SESSION['depart']."'
```

And then again... the field `dates` will only work if only 1 table has this field name. Just to be safe... make it bus.dates.